# How to deduce enum elements?

Tags: c++, enums

I need to write a spell book and I have two ways to do it - use enum, or use std :: map, as it is easier for me to use enum. But I ran into a problem how to display my enum?

I want to make it so that I can display all these spells on the screen and ask the user which of these spells do you want to use?

for example:

```
enum Book {
Tornado,
FireBall,
etc,
};
```

I want it to be output to the console like this :

```
choose one:

1.Tornado
2.FireBall
```

how to output this,for example with using array,is it possible?

Comment: The questinon is very unclear. What output do you expect when you do what? But anyway my crystal ball tells me you probably should use `std::map` (which BTW is pretty easy to use.)

Comment: So... are you asking how to turn `Tornado` into `"Tornado"` so that it may be printed?

Comment: _" But I ran into a problem how to display my enum?"_  which problem exactly? Did you get an error message? Did your code display something else than you expected? [Edit] and tell us more.

Comment: the problem is that I do not know how to implement it, I wrote it

Comment: @smth you need to tell us what you're trying to achieve. What exactly do you want to implement?

Comment: Create a vector containing your book strings, for example, `vector<string> books {"Tornado", "FireBall"};` And print it using `cout<<books[enum value];`.

Comment: Create `enums` and then the text to match the enums with the associated arrays and counters.  Then write loops.  Or just use the `std::map` that does that already and uses iterators.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the enum (Tornado, FireBall) instead of 1, 2 you can create a separate function doing that display

```
#include <iostream>


enum Book {
Tornado,
FireBall,
};

void yourFunction(const Book& book)
{
    switch(book)
    {
        case Book::Tornado:
            std::cout<<"Tornado"<<std::endl;
            break;
        case Book::FireBall:
            std::cout<<"FireBall"<<std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Book b=Book::FireBall;
    yourFunction(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about keeping the function and enum in sync? That's not something to be skimmed over. Also, the pass by reference is a premature pessimization.

Comment: What if I need to display all the contents of my enum at once, and not separately?

Answer (score 0):

The general problem described here is associating a known integer value with a text string. The solution can be as straightforward as this:

```
enum Book {
    Tornado,
    Fireball,
    last_index // see below
};
static const char* names[] = {
    "Tornado",
    "Fireball"
};
```

To display the menu, just go through the enumerators:

```
for (int i = Tornado; i < last_index; ++i)
    std::cout << (i + 1) << '.' << names[i] << '\n';
```

You can do this because enumerators start at 0 and increase by 1, that is, the value of `Tornado` is 0 and the value of `Fireball` is 1. The value of `last_index` is 2.

The reason for using `last_index` is to make it easier to maintain the code. If you add an enumerator that loop doesn't change:

```
enum Book {
    Tornado,
    Fireball,
    GladHands,
    last_index // see below
};
static const char* names[] = {
    "Tornado",
    "Fireball",
    "Glad Hands"
};
```

With the added enumerator, the value of `GladHands` is 2 and the value of `last_index` is 3, so the original loop still works.

Note that this does not generate text from the name of the enumerator. The name of the enumerator has restrictions on it that the text version doesn't, so you really can't generate text in most cases. In particular, `GladHands` has no spaces, but its text version has one.

Comment: what I was imagining in my head, but could not implement it! thanks!